# particle.js doesnt show after site preload

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm `preloading` site with `jQuery` and the problem is, when the `preload` is done, site shows up but there are 0 animations from `particle.js`. At the start of `CSS` file i'm hiding whole content in `.content{display:none;}` and later on `content` is showing up via `fadeIn` function. But `particles` are still in `display:none` whatever happens after `preload function` is done.

Things i've tried:

1. `$('.content').show();` instead of `fadeIn`
2. `$('.content').css('display', 'block');` instead of `fadeIn`
3. Before `preload function` and without `.content{display:none;}`  in `CSS` `$('.content').addClass('displayNone');`, inside function after `$(windows).load... $('.content').removeClass('displayNone');`
4. Switching scripts loading first, like `app.js` loaded before `jquery`; from having them in `<head>` to before `</body>` tag
5. Switching initialization of `preload function` and `particles`, like `particles(...)` and after that `$(window).load(...);`

I'm currently out of ideas how to load animations from `particle.js` after `site preload` so any tips/tricks would be highly appreciated and for sure I will consider any option. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZVwLz
In codepen, outside `.content` `particles` are working but then, the particles are loaded before `preload function`, when `particles` are inside `.content`, `particles` are not working.

**EDIT #2 (SOLVED):** Found solution, had to change in `CSS` `.content{display: none;}` to `.content{visibility: hidden;}` with `$('.content').css('visibility', 'visible');` in JS. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KMPPQB

Comment: you have "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )" error message, fix this error message, might be the reason you're code is not functioning properly.

Comment: Well, i'm not going to insert whole CSS, HTML, JS into snippet, just the most important parts where the problem is.

Comment: @nehel And you expect people to simply look at your code and *guess* what the problem is?

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Well, described my problem but mostly in theory which is my bad. Didn't notice that point of view, thanks for that. Added working codepen.

Comment: @nehel I took a look at your code, but I've got *zero* experience with the  particle library, so I'm afraid I can't track anything down.